# Finding a basis for a linear map in a different field

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

**Question** Let $B = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ and let $C = \{1\}$ Let $f: U \rightarrow V$ be a linear map given by the matrix $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      2+i&1-3i&4i    
    \end{array}
\right] $$

with respect to bases $B$ and $C$.

Now let us view $U$ and $V$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ with U having basis $$D=\lbrace(1,0,0),(i,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,i,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,i)\rbrace$$ and $V$ having basis $E  = \lbrace1,i\rbrace$

Find the matrix of the same map $f$ with respect to $D$ and $E$

**My attempt**

$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
     2 & -1 & 1 & 3& 0& -4\\
     1 & 2 & -3 & 1 & 4& 0\\
     \end{pmatrix}$$

However I am unsure about whether am I correct. I have done this by using the matrix with respect to $B$ and $C$ which is why I feel I have gone wrong somewhere. Is this method and answer correct?

Comment: This looks reasonable to me.